# Anyone knows what this part is on RPi 4? Need help identifying it

Tags: pi-4, power

something went wrong. After fresh Ubuntu installation Pi got stuck at bootloop. After a few times of crashing and rebooting i guessed bad ISO so i wanted to take the card out. That's how i ended up with a blister on my thumb. I was amazed how hot something can get with only 5v. The supply is Pi4's original. Anyhow, there on the board was something black, squared and it poped. Jumped out, never to be seen again. Nothing was connected to PI except HDMI monitor that i use and usb dongle for keyboard. Can anyone tell me what it might be? I would try to source it somehow and send to a cellphone repair shop. Maybe (i hope) they will be able to fix it if provided with a missing part. Thanks, Lemi[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an inductor in the power circuitry.

Don't bother trying to replace it - it is a symptom of the problem (which is probably a damaged PMIC) not the problem. If you did replace it it would almost certainly fail again.

Comment: And your opinion on changing both by a pro guy?